# Where to start with Google Reader as an API?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, google-reader

I want to build a widget for WordPress that simultaneously displays my latest Google Reader items on the front page and allows for management from behind the WordPress dashboard.  I can already add my "shared" items using code I've found in various Google searches, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I like the functionality of the Google Reader widget in iGoogle, and I want to replicate that on the WordPress dashboard and build a read-only version for the WordPress front-end.  Where do I start in the API (public or 'unofficial') to get this built?

-- Update --

I've found some limited documentation regarding authentication protocols, but I've been unable to implement anything.  I can parse a URL to authenticate and get an SSID that works when directly placed in a browser, but both GET and POST requests fail via PHP, so I can't get any further than that.

-- Update --

[I've converted the first few steps of Martin Doms' C# tutorial into PHP](http://mindsharestrategy.com/google-reader-api-a-brief-tutorial/) for anyone who's interested in doing this on their own site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a nice 3-step tutorial: http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/08/15/using-the-google-reader-api-part-1/

If you're having problems from PHP, then I think you should post the PHP code to see where it's failing. These steps should work flawlessly.

Comment: I actually started with that tutorial.  And the problem with PHP isn't actually a problem with PHP ... it's a problem with authentication in general (possibly from my domain, but I'm not sure ...)

I ported the C# code to PHP, and the issue occurs in the getSID() function.  I can use the parsed URL (https://www.google.com/accounts...) directly in a web browser to return an SID and LSID, but both POST and GET requests via PHP throw an HTTP security violation.

Comment: How are you doing those POST and GET from PHP? Using cURL function to do a GET should work just fine (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php). If you're still having problems, posting your current code may help.

Comment: I'll try again with cURL and let you know what happens.

Comment: cURL ended up being the magic that did the trick.  After I was able to get the SID, the hardest step was passing a cookie in the GET request to return an auth token.  Now everything's working beautifully, though.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark this answer as correct when you have the time ;)

Comment: I will ... it keeps telling me I have to wait.  Right now it's down to 1 hour, so you'll have your bounty soon enough :-)

Comment: Oh, forgot this one was a bounty one! Better yet! :) I always ask to mark as correct if they don't do it, so others can know which answer is *the* one pretty quickly.

Comment: I've also added a PHP version of Martin Doms' tutorial on my own site: http://mindsharestrategy.com/google-reader-api-a-brief-tutorial/

Comment: The site went dead.. Anyone knows where can i find this tut (i'm more of a c# guy :) thanks.

Comment: Here's another C# tutorial explaining the same process: http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/Consuming-Google-(Reader)-with-NET-Part-1-Authentication.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I can add some extra resources, especially the ones that resemble the most a structured documentation for this unofficial API:

- http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI - Very good and structured API documentation.
- http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/10/16/using-the-google-reader-api-part-2 - (Already referred above) Also a well structured API documentation, in 3 parts. Contains some details not seen elsewhere.
- http://www.chrisdadswell.co.uk/android-coding-example-authenticating-clientlogin-google-reader-api/ - Good resource for coding examples and API documentation
- http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi/ - 'Official' group for the unofficial Google Reader API. Lots of advanced questions, often answered by Google developers. Not good for structured documentation though...

Hope it helps!

Comment: The Google group 'fourgrapi' is a great resource for questions that will pop-up when trying to interface with Google Reader. Thanks! +1 for sharing that

Answer (score 0):

Following up on EAMann his PHP class is here http://code.google.com/p/greader-library/source/browse/trunk/greader.class.php?r=4. I got it working last night. Thank you Eric, I will be adding to your library.

Comment: Feel free to submit patches to the Issues section on Google Reader as well.  Anything you can contribute will help make the library stronger!