# Is there a documented Google Reader API yet?

Tags: rss, google-reader

In late 2005, Niall Kennedy blogged about Google Reader’s API: http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2005/12/google-reader-api.html

He mentioned that a couple of guys at Google suggested to him that the API might be made official within a couple of weeks.

Has the API ever been officially and publicly documented by Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, despite the talk about Google doing this some day, there is no officially documented Google Reader API yet.

However, the API has been [unofficially documented](http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI).

Answer (score 1):

Related: [Where to start with Google Reader as an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752076/where-to-start-with-google-reader-as-an-api)

Answer (score 1):

I've been successfully using https://github.com/brutuscat/googlereader that is a fork of http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/

If you want to see more samples, I wrote an [article](http://blog.databigbang.com/extraction-of-main-text-content/) about how to use the lib to extract the main text content from an HTML. This is an alternative to boilerpipe mainly for blogs.