# Are there any google reader api?

Tags: oauth, google-reader

I need import user's google reader feeds to my site, any way can do this?

I can't find google reader API, it's great if there is an node.js implementation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a documented Google Reader API yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632420/is-there-a-documented-google-reader-api-yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of documentation available for the Google Reader API; material published by both Google and the wider community is easily found with a quick search, or by browsing the Google developer pages.

---

The various things you'll need to investigate are:

- Authorizing your credentials with Google via [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html#OAuth) or [ClientLogin](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html).
- Obtaining the user's list of feeds via http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/list (XML format).

When I started writing this, I could've sworn there would be more steps... but, that's it!
Google has the nack to make things simple, yet so powerful.